# multiple wildcards in URI Routing not working

Tags: regex, codeigniter, url

i am having an odd issue with codeigniter's URI Routes functionality...specifically surrounding the use of wildcards.

i am trying to have the following URL routed to my 'locations' controller, calling my 'edit' method:

```
http://foo.bar/stores/4fdbc15b8e08233c6d9f7d91/locations/4fdbc2ed8e08233c6d9f7d93/edit
```

i have the following setup in my routes config file:

```
$route['stores/(:any)/locations/(:any)/edit'] = 'locations/edit';
```

however...when i try to path to the above URL, the site dies.

i have tried to use regex but unfortunately regex is not my strong point, thus it too is not working.

i have looked at other stackoverflow examples and other sites, but nothing really speaks to the odd URL structure i have.  any suggestions/resolutions would be much appreciated.  thanks in advance for the assistance!

Comment: I suggest you to check your logs for more information. I just test it on my server, and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: sorry all...it appears that the issue is something elsewhere which i had not foreseen.  the URI router in CI appears to be working.  if i am still at a wall...i will update my post.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this route. In CI's source code the "(:any)" gets replaced with a regex string to represent anything, so there's no need to have a regex. What do you mean 'the site dies'?

Comment: How are the strings in the request URI used? or are they used at all?

Comment: turns out the issue was a missing parathesis in a utility function i was calling only for this method.  that is why other sections of the site were working and this one died.  the only thing i *thought* was different between this and other working routes was the complex URI structure.  sooo...this is resolved and i am walking away from this with my tail between my legs.  sorry for the post, but much thanks to all who jumped on this to help out!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings in your request uri are variable length, you could try something like this:

```
$route['stores/([a-z0-9]*)/locations/([a-z0-9]*)/edit'] = 'locations/edit';
```

However you didn't clarify what is to be done with the strings matched by the regex.  If you simply appended them to the end, your route would look like this:

```
$route['stores/([a-z0-9]*)/locations/([a-z0-9]*)/edit'] = 'locations/edit/$1/$2';
```

In which case, in your controller method you could use the [$this->uri_segment()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) function to parse out the strings.

```
$firstHash = $this->uri_segment(3);
$secondHash = $this->uri_segment(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple technique to do what you wanted to do

```
$route['stores/(:any)'] = 'locations/edit';
```

then, using **uri_segment(n)** get the value in in edit controller function.

Simple?